# make select option clickable, but keep it from populating the select input view reactstrap Input

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a select with an option called "+ Create new"

When the user clicks on this option, I am showing a modal to create a new option, however I do not want this select option to render + create new after the option is clicked.

How can I keep the option "clickable" but keep it from populating the selects actual input view?

here is the component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Input } from 'reactstrap'

const TestComponent = () => {

const [upload, setUpload] = useState({
selectHeader: []
})

 const [showFieldModal, setShowFieldModal] = useState(false);

return (
              <Fragment>
                <Input
                  type="select"
                  name="selectHeader"
                  id="selectHeader"
                  onChange={({ target }) => {
                    if(target.value === "+ Create new") {
                      setShowFieldModal(!showFieldModal)
                    } else {
                      setUpload({...upload, selectHeader: [...upload.selectHeader, {value: target.value, index: index}]})
                    }
                  }}
                 >
                   <option>First name</option>
                   <option>Last name</option>
                 
                    <option>+ Create new</option> // make this clickable but dont allow it to show as the selects option when clicked....
                 </Input>
                </Fragment>
);
};

           export default TestComponent;
```

This code below takes in consideration the accepted answer but adds the functionality if you need to map over an array and render multiple Inputs with type="select" that do not allow the select to actually render the "+ create new" option

Note: the id is updated to `` . id={`selectHeader${index}`} ``   and the onChange is updated to `` document.getElementById(`selectHeader${index}`).value= " " ; ``

````
<Table responsive bordered striped hover>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {
            fileContacts.map((contact, index) => (
                <th className="bg-primary pr-1 pl-1 pt-2 pb-2 overflow-hidden" scope="col" key={index}>
                  <Input
                  type="select"
                  className="fs--1"
                  name="selectHeader"
                  id={`selectHeader${index}`}
                  onChange={({ target }) => {
                    
                    if(target.value === "+ Create new") {
                      document.getElementById(`selectHeader${index}`).value= " " ;
                      setShowFieldModal(!showFieldModal)
                    } else {
                      setUpload({...upload, selectHeader: [...upload.selectHeader, {value: target.value, index: index}]})
                    }
                  }}
                 >
                   
                   <option>First name</option>
                   <option>Last name</option>
                  
                 { fields.map((field, index) => (
                   <option key={index} >{field.title}</option> 
                 ))}
                    <option>+ Create new</option>
                 </Input>
                </th>  
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {
        upload.contacts.slice(0, 10).map((customer, index) => (
          <TableRow data={customer} key={index}/>
        ))
        }
      </tbody>
    </Table>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try, you need to empty the select value after clicking on the option, this might help you

```
onChange={({ target }) => {
     if(target.value === "+ Create new") {
        document.getElementById('selectHeader').value= " " ;
        setShowFieldModal(!showFieldModal)
     } else {
        setUpload({...upload, selectHeader: [...upload.selectHeader, {value: 
        target.value, index: index}]})
     }
}}
```